# Android Custom Keyboard with Custom Button for each user

Tags: android, android-studio, special-characters, custom-keyboard

I have a specific requirement for providing every user a custom button that will only be available for him on the keyboard. The Custom Button can be any like (%,#,@,etc or may be numeric). How can i add that on the Custom Keyboard any ideas. I have already added the custom keyboard in my app but i also need this button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set custom text to that little blue button. In the xml file just use

```
android:imeActionLabel="userName"
```

You can do this programatically as well like

```
etEditText.setImeActionLabel("userName", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

And if you what the Button onClickListner than use

```
etEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**It should be noted** that this will not cause text to appear on all keyboards on all devices. Some keyboards do not support text on that button (e.g. swiftkey). And some devices don't support it either. A good rule is, if you see text already on the button, this will change it to whatever you'd want.

Comment: No i want to add a Button suggested by the user specifically for that user only. The Button Suggested should appear on his device keyboard only.

Comment: Yes bro !! thats  your  logic  means you have to check dynamiclly  user like Switch(username) {
  case "usernameOne":  
         etEditText.setImeActionLabel("usernameOne", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

      break;

case "usernameTwo":  
         etEditText.setImeActionLabel("usernameTwo", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

      break;
}

Comment: for usernameOne it show his name on keyboard  as 'usernameOne '  for  usernameTwo show name like 'usernameTwo'